# Is there a way to export chat history in Skype 5.2.x for OS X?

Tags: skype, history

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [Is there a way to export chat history in Skype 5.2.x for OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/312119/is-there-a-way-to-export-chat-history-in-skype-5-2-x-for-os-x)

I'm currently running 5.2.x on OS X 10.6.8 and I need to some deep searching of the past history in a conversation with a colleague. Skype tells me the term I'm looking for is in the long-running chat we've had, but good luck getting it to show you the specific chat entry in time without manually scrolling backwards through months and months of back-and-forth.

I'd like to export the conversation as some format I can access programmatically (HTML, XML, etc.). The HTML export options that used to be present in Skype for OS X seem to have disappeared as of the 5.0 release.

**Is there a way to export chat history in Skype 5.2.x for OS X?**

Comment: I got an answer to this question on SuperUser.com. Close here? http://superuser.com/questions/312119/is-there-a-way-to-export-chat-history-in-skype-5-2-x-for-os-x

Comment: Closing at your request

Answer (score 1):

try the SQLite export method @ http://billxinli.com/2011/07/28/export-skype-chat-history-and-other-meta-data/ =)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.